# CSS - Progress bar not appearing in Safari and not animated on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, safari, progress-bar

I made a progress bar which is styled and animated. It is looking good on Opera and Chrome, however I have 2 problems with Firefox and Safari:

- The animation effect is not working on Firefox
- The progress bar is not appearing at all on Safari

Can anyone help? I write the code below.
Thanks in advance!

Bobby

HTML CODE

```
<progress value="67" min="0" max="100"></progress>
```

CSS CODE

```
progress {
    width: 400px;
    height: 14px;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    display: block;
    padding: 1px;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background-size:auto;
    border-radius:15px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #747467, #515145 49%, #414137 50%, #54544B);
    /*background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #747467, #515145 49%, #414137 50%, #54544B);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #747467, #515145 49%, #414137 50%, #54544B);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #747467, #515145 49%, #414137 50%, #54544B);*/
    /*background-image: none;*/
}


progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #747467, #515145 49%, #414137 50%, #54544B);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-align:left;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 66%, transparent 66%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(top, #70AAE2, #4791DA 49%, #3385D6 50%, #4791DA);
        /*-moz-linear-gradient(left, #70AAE2, #4791DA);*/
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    text-align:left;
    background-size: 25px 14px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    -moz-animation: move 5s linear 0 infinite;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    background:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 66%, transparent 66%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #70AAE2, #4791DA 49%, #3385D6 50%, #4791DA);
        /*-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #70AAE2, #4791DA);*/
    background-size: 25px 14px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation: move 5s linear 0 infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
    100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
    100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly an answer but more of a suggestion.

Why dont you use bootstrap? It takes care of everything for you:

Normal Progress Bar:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;"></div>
</div>
```

Striped:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
</div>
```

and much more.. Check this: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#progress

To include bootstrap, do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score -2):

The HTML `<progress>` Element is used to view the completion progress of a task. While the specifics of how it's displayed is left up to the browser developer, it's typically displayed as a progress bar but looks differently in every browser. JavaScript can be used to manipulate the value of progress bar.

Chrome: works as you expect it to

Firefox:  component implementation is like this way.

Safari: check your browser version

for more detailed info:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: OP is asking about specific browser behavior around rendering progress bars, not a general tutorial on them.